# Selenium Python How Do I Read the child elements of the '//following' td tag?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I have this list that I need to cycle through until I reach the munprod DB on the host server ending with "01". I'm using the code below and apparently have a syntactical error that I cannot figure out because it's dropping into the code for the if statement as if it were true, but it's doing it for host = '02' and not '01'.

```
#5. Select munprod from Availability Groups tab **NOTE: There are 2 munprods, get the one on 01...NOT 02
munprods = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'munprod')]")))
for munprod in munprods:
    munprodServer = munprod.find_element(By.XPATH, '//following::td')
    if munprodServer.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(), "01.jefferson.ketsds.net")]'):
        munprod.click()
        logger.info("Step 5: Databases --> munprod 01.jefferson.ketsds.net selected")
        break
```

I know it's host '02' because when it hits the munprod.click() line it goes to the next screen and shows that it's for host '02'.  Can a pair of fresh eyes spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a 'period' (.) in front of your XPath expressions when looking for some element(s) under already located element.

This will ensure that your starting point is the element you are doing 'find_element' from.

So:

```
 munprodServer = munprod.find_element(By.XPATH, '//following::td')
```

Should be:

```
munprodServer = munprod.find_element(By.XPATH, './/following::td')
```

And:

```
if munprodServer.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(), "01.jefferson.ketsds.net")]'):
```

Should be:

```
if munprodServer.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[contains(text(), "01.jefferson.ketsds.net")]'):
```

Without the period, Selenium may search over the entire document, which could lead to some random and unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

i would update the selectors to use the defined XPath `normalize-space` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space

Several use cases:

- Lets say you have `01.jefferson.ketsds.net` and `101.jefferson.ketsds.net`

Using `'.//div[contains(text(), "01.jefferson.ketsds.net")]'` will match both results.

With normalize space, as in your case will match only single result ex:

```
//div[normalize-space(.) = '01.jefferson.ketsds.net']
```

For more complex text, that are nested into single element ex:

```
<h1>
    <span>Hello</span> lorem ipsum.
</h1>
```

You would like to check find the element with `lorem ipsum`
In that case, we can use the normalize space and text() function.

```
//h1[text()[normalize-space(.) = 'lorem ipsum.']]
```

XPath functions are very useful for complex selectors and matching.

More information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions